# Database manipulation in Java EE

Tags: java, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I know the usual way of connecting Java application to to the database using the following code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
DriverManager .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/.......");
```

How about in Java EE? Is there a new approach in database manipulation or should I use the same code above?

Comment: You would want to set up a data source in the container and then inject it when you need it. Or inject a PersistenceContext and use JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java EE, you should use the [Java Persistence API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) (JPA).
1. You should create a data source in your container.
2. Configure the persistence.xml in your project.
3. Inject the EntityManager (javax.persistence.EntityManager) object with the @PersistenceContext (javax.persistence.PersistenceContext) annotation.
4. And, use it. For example

```
public YourObject findById(Integer id) {
    return em.find(YourObject.class, id);
}
public void persist(YourObject entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
}
public void update(YourObject entity) {
    em.merge(entity);
}
public void delete(YourObject entity) {
    em.remove(entity);
}
```

I hope it helps.